# Recursive function and "let in" errors

Tags: ocaml

I am trying to figure out what this function does, and when I run it in my code editor, it is giving me a syntax error at the "end in". I have tried putting brackets around "let x" and some other places, but I am at a loss. I would appreciate any help in understanding why I am getting an error.

```
let rec map (f: 'a -> 'b) (y: 'a list): 'b list =
  begin match y with
  | [] -> []
  | h :: t -> (f h) :: (map f t)
  end in
 let x = map (fun t -> (t + 1) [0; 1; 2] in
 0 :: x
```

Comment: Check your parens, it's unbalanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to accomplish?

```
let () =
  let rec map f y =
    match y with
    | [] -> []
    | h :: t -> (f h) :: (map f t)
  in
  let x = map (fun t -> t + 1) [0; 1; 2] in
  0 :: x
  |> List.iter (fun x -> Printf.printf "%d\n" x)
```